# How to include commonjs module in ES6 module node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, commonjs

I have a node app that I'd like to use in the standard ES6 module format (i.e., [`"type": "module"` in the `package.json`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field), and using `import` and `export` throughout) without transpiling down to ES5. But I would like to take advantage of some older libraries such as a express and socket.io that use CommonJS / `require` format. What are my options (as of 5/2020, Node 12.16.3) for combining CommonJS modules into an ES6 app?

Comment: You can mix and match the two? I don't think you'll have any issues.

Answer (score 37):

Working with CommonJS modules is pretty straight forward.
You can only do `default` exports from CommonJS modules.

```js
import packageMain from 'commonjs-package'; // Works
import { method } from 'commonjs-package'; // Errors
```

This means that all commonjs exports will live on the `packageMain` object, and you need to *dot* in to the packageMain object to pickup what you need.

```js
packageMain.method1()
```

More info in the [official nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements)

Comment: Starting from nodejs `v14.13.0` it is [possible to use](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/35249) qualified imports of CJS modules.

Answer (score 14):

Since Node 13.10, there is another option, the most forward-looking one:

File an issue in the repo of the CommonJS library you'd like to use, [persuading the maintainers](https://github.com/lukeed/typescript-module/issues/1) to publish [dual packages](https://alexomara.com/blog/dual-packages-in-node-js-conditional-exports/) (ESM + CommonJS), using [conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports).

For libraries written in TypeScript, generating dual packages is easy, and doesn't require Babel or rollup or any additional tools. Here's how I did it in [local-iso-dt](https://github.com/dandv/local-iso-dt):

Relevant parts of **package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "local-iso-dt",
  "version": "3.1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "exports": {
    "node": {
      "import": "./index.mjs",
      "require": "./index.js"
    },
    "default": "./index.mjs"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "files": [
    "index.ts",
    "index.mjs",
    "index.js"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm index*.js index.mjs",
    "prepublishOnly:cjs": "tsc index.ts --esModuleInterop --removeComments",
    "prepublishOnly:esm": "tsc index.ts -t ES2015 --types node && mv index.js index.mjs",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run prepublishOnly:esm; npm run prepublishOnly:cjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
}
```

`prepublishOnly:esm` renames the output manually because [TypeScript can't yet generate `.mjs` output directly](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18442) and `--outFile` doesn't work with ES Modules.

The `exports` block has the "[conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_conditional_exports) that enable TypeScript code transpiled with ES Modules, to use named imports. [TypeScript doesn't directly support .mjs input files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27957).

No `tsconfig.json` was necessary for this simple module.

Answer (score 4):

Ivan's answer is helpful, but I also should note that that because I was using node 12.16.3, I also needed to add the `--experimental-modules` flag to my start script in `package.json`:

```
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-modules --experimental-json-modules server.mjs",
}
```

- `"type": "module"` tells node that you should use ES6 modules
- file name of `.mjs` further makes it clear that we're working with a module JavaScript file
- `--experimental-modules` and `--experimental-json-modules` let you use `import` in node version 12.

Then I was able to do things like `import express from 'express';` (where express 4.17.1 is a CommonJS module), and it worked fine.

Comment: Almost everything tried after 8 hours of struggling... Thank you my savior

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the module in question has an `index.js` that exports the code you want to `import` or `require`.

In `package.json`, under the `dependencies` attribute, add:

```
"myCustomModule":"file:./path/to/myCustomModule"
```

After you have done this run `npm install`.

Once that is completed look inside the project's `node_modules/` and you will see a directory named `myCustomModule`.

Now in any project file you can `import` or `require` that code as you would any other `mode_module`

Comment: How does an index.js export code you want to import? The module in question is a commonjs module.