# The requested module '@azure/arm-authorization' is expected to be of type CommonJS

Tags: node.js, azure-java-sdk

I am using Node 14.5.0 with a default Express.JS installation. I need to leverage the Azure SDK for Node using Imports and have changed the default express require from:

```
const express = require('express')
```

to:

```
import express from 'express';
```

Express is able to load, but when I add the example SDK for authorization (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/authorization/arm-authorization) it is throwing the following error:

> import { AuthorizationManagementClient, AuthorizationManagementModels,
> AuthorizationManagementMappers } from "@azure/arm-authorization";
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: The requested module '@azure/arm-authorization' is expected to be of type CommonJS,
> which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported
> by importing the default export. For example: import pkg from
> '@azure/arm-authorization'; const { AuthorizationManagementClient,
> AuthorizationManagementModels, AuthorizationManagementMappers } = pkg;
> at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:98:21)
> at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:137:5)
> at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:162:24)

I have already added "type": "module", to my package.json and installed the modules listed in the Azure SDK page.

My App.JS page is as follows:

```
import express from 'express';
import * as msRest from "@azure/ms-rest-js";
import * as msRestAzure from "@azure/ms-rest-azure-js";
import * as msRestNodeAuth from "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth";
import { AuthorizationManagementClient, AuthorizationManagementModels, AuthorizationManagementMappers } from "@azure/arm-authorization";
const subscriptionId = process.env["myguideforsubhere"];
const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))

msRestNodeAuth.interactiveLogin().then((creds) => {
    const client = new AuthorizationManagementClient(creds, subscriptionId);
    client.classicAdministrators.list().then((result) => {
      console.log("The result is:");
      console.log(result);
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

My Package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myproject",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/arm-authorization": "^8.3.2",
    "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth": "^3.0.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Does this look like an error in the SDK documentation where it can't use the imports as exampled but needs to be changed to require, or more likely, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See [How to include commonjs module in ES6 module node app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61549406/1366033)

```js
import { method } from 'commonjs-package';  // Errors
import packageMain from 'commonjs-package'; // Works
```

In your case, the azure sdk isn't written with `"type": "module"` so node treats it as a commonjs module, not an es6 module.  So, you'll have to import and destructure in two separate steps:

```js
import armAuth from "@azure/arm-authorization";
let { AuthorizationManagementClient, AuthorizationManagementModels } = armAuth;
```

**See Also**: [requested module does not provide an export named '*'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54302557/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your node version to 16 or above. It fixed my errors